# How to get Python csv.writer & csv.writerows to write to next lines, instead of writing over previous cells?

Tags: python, csv, reader, writer

I am trying to get Python to write 5 lines of text to a CSV file, but not to keep rewriting from the cell [A1].

At the current moment, the program is able to write to the first cell, filling the variables I need into the text. Though the csv.write and csv.writerows keeps overwriting from cell [A1] instead of adding them onto the bottom e.g. cell [A10].

Is there a function that I can use that skips to e.g. cell [A10] every time it writes in the loop that I have provided below?

I have tried to use the newline='' feature, but I am not sure if that even is relevant. I am quite new to python.

```
import csv

with open("TGC_Mailout_001_13-05-2019_retarget.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader) #skip header row
    for email, name, corp in reader:
        contents = [[f'Hi {name} I hope this email finds you well.'],
                    [""],
                    [f'I was wondering if you had a chance to take a look at my previous email regarding the Wellness - Mindfulness program opportunity for {corp}.'],
                    [""],
                    ['It would be great to connect with you for a quick chat to let you know more about the program and see what you are currently doing in the space of wellness.'],
                    [""],
                    [f'With stress rising around the demanding nature of work, long hours & technology reshaping working lives (always being connected), I believe {corp} would really benefit from this program.'],
                    [""],
                    ['Kind regards']]
        retarget = open("TGC_Retarget_001_21-05-2019.csv", 'w')
        #Below block is getting py to dump the text into CSV, but it is rewriting over the text each time it reads and writes 
        #We want the below to skip to the bottom of last line of text, then keep dumping the text with new variables from CSV file 
        with retarget:
            writer = csv.writer(retarget)
            writer.writerows(contents)
            print ('Writing complete')
```

**Desired output:**

,

Hi Sean I hope this email finds you well.

I was wondering if you had a chance to take a look at my previous email regarding the Wellness - Mindfulness program opportunity for Company.

It would be great to connect with you for a quick chat to let you know more about the program and see what you are currently doing in the space of wellness.

With stress rising around the demanding nature of work, long hours & technology reshaping working lives (always being connected), I believe Company would really benefit from this program.

Kind regards

,

Hi Carrie I hope this email finds you well.

I was wondering if you had a chance to take a look at my previous email regarding the Wellness - Mindfulness program opportunity for Company.

It would be great to connect with you for a quick chat to let you know more about the program and see what you are currently doing in the space of wellness.

With stress rising around the demanding nature of work, long hours & technology reshaping working lives (always being connected), I believe Company would really benefit from this program.

Kind regards

,

Etc. etc. etc. x 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are repeatedly opening your output file in `w` mode, which truncates the file before writing. Open in `a` (append) mode instead:

```
    retarget = open("TGC_Retarget_001_21-05-2019.csv", 'a')
```

or better yet, open the file *before* the loop and leave it open.

```
import csv

with open("TGC_Mailout_001_13-05-2019_retarget.csv") as file, \
     open("TGC_Retarget_001_21-05-2019.csv", 'w') as retarget:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    writer = csv.writer(retarget)
    next(reader) #skip header row
    for email, name, corp in reader:
        contents = [[f'Hi {name} I hope this email finds you well.'],
                    [""],
                    [f'I was wondering if you had a chance to take a look at my previous email regarding the Wellness - Mindfulness program opportunity for {corp}.'],
                    [""],
                    ['It would be great to connect with you for a quick chat to let you know more about the program and see what you are currently doing in the space of wellness.'],
                    [""],
                    [f'With stress rising around the demanding nature of work, long hours & technology reshaping working lives (always being connected), I believe {corp} would really benefit from this program.'],
                    [""],
                    ['Kind regards']]

        writer = csv.writer(retarget)
        writer.writerows(contents)
    print ('Writing complete')
```